# visual Studio Updates (2019 latest version)

Tags: visual-studio

How can I update my visual studio while my server does not connect to any networks? I need to copy a download file to my server and then execute that file. Please tell me how can I do this? Is there any link that I can get my download? I couldn't find it in Microsoft downloads!!!Need to Update with no internet connections(offline update)// If you know please provide the steps so many people can use it as a solution. Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 and you'll need to use an updated full installer to update an installation.

Comment: How can I use it for update?

Comment: Give it a try: I would expect it to apply updates if there is already an install.

Comment: @Richard, I haven't tried it yet but if you know the steps , please write it down as an answer. I am going to do it next week, if I got succeeded I will bring my solution in here.thanks